# SignalR Context.User.Identity.Name showing null (Dotnet 6)

Tags: .net, .net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

We are using dotnet 6 of our webapi.

We already use authentication and we get all user data in the HttpContext.

Still, Unable to set this data in SignalR Context.

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR(configure =>
{
 configure.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = null;

 configure.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
});
```

=============

```
app.UseHttpStatusCodeMiddleware();

app.UseCookiePolicy();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapControllers();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/hubs/chat");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

SignalR connection is different than the normal request, it's built by websocket.

A single user in SignalR can have multiple connections to an app. For example, a user could be connected on their desktop as well as their phone. Each device has a separate SignalR connection, but they're all associated with the same user. If a message is sent to the user, all of the connections associated with that user receive the message. The user identifier for a connection can be accessed by the Context.UserIdentifier property in the hub.

By default, SignalR uses the ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier from the ClaimsPrincipal associated with the connection as the user identifier.

So if you want to use the user name you could try to use `User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value`.

Besides, if you want to modify the userid, you should customized [IUserIdProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.iuseridprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0) like this and register it as an singleton.

```
   public class UserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
    {
        public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
        {
            return connection.User.FindFirst(ClaimConstants.PreferredUserName).Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: main issue is I'm not able to set HubConnectionContext properties 
in the HubContext only value which is available is ConnectionID
I want to set other properties as well which will give more user data (name, GUID, . . .)

is there any way we could set HubContext Claims through the caller/client ?
or
I already have all the data in httpContext can I reassign same data in HubContext ? somehow !

Comment: As I said in the answer, you should store these information by customsize the IUserIdProvider or if you want to store more information, you should store the user information when the connect started in server memory or other server like sql server. Then your hub could read these information inside the server memory or sql server